# Why does the height of the block header increase when making references to self-made environments? How to avoid this?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am making a beamer presentation using MikTex 2.9 and I have made some environments on my own. I want to be able to make references to these environments, but when I do so, the height of the block header increases for some reason.

```
\newcounter{theo}[part]
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{theo}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{theo}
\newenvironment<>{theo}[2]{
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=dgreen!100!white}
\begin{block}{\refstepcounter{theo}\label{#2}Saetning~\thetheo #1}}{\end{block}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=dgreen!100!white}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=dgreen!100!white}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=dgreen!100!white}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=dgreen!100!black}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{\setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=dgreen!100!black}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{\setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=dgreen!100!black}}
```

The output looks fine except that the block header is considerably taller (it grows with approximately a factor of 1.67) than if I don't want to be able to make references to theorems. The problem is present nomatter if I actually do make a reference to a certain theorem or not. The above code is meant to make those references possible. And this is enough to create this block-header-height-problem. I am not using the built-in theorem-environment because I am making my beamer-presentations in Danish (Saetning is Danish for Theorem) and I also want to customize the environments by coloring the bullet-points in the same color as the block header. Can anybody help me out? I am using \usetheme{Aalborg} by the way.

Comment: Can you please make a minimal compilable example instead of a code fragment? Also why not simply use beamers build-in theorem environment?

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel, beamer has mechanism in place for translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to define a new environment, I would simply use the build-in `theorem` environment and translation mechanism provided by beamer.

To adjust it to the same formatting as you have shown in your question, a few minor tweaks can be made:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Aalborg}

\uselanguage{danish}
\languagepath{danish}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Theorem}{Saetning}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
    }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
    \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
        $a^2+b^2=c^2$ 
        \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \end{itemize}
        \label{pytagoras}
    \end{theorem}

    Theorem \ref{pytagoras}

    \begin{block}{Title Pythagoras}
        content...
        \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code solved the problem! :-) I have a few other questions: 1) the text in a theorem is now formatted in textit or textsl, but I want it to be formatted as before, which is normal text. How can I do that? 2) I want to make exampleblocks just like the theoremblocks with the same formatting as the theoremblocks (except I want the block header background color to be cyan). How can I do that? I tried to copy-paste your code and replace 'theorem' with 'example', but it didn't work out.

Comment: @PeterJensen Can you please use the "Ask question" button on the top left to ask new questions? Comments are not a good place.